# access method inside of require js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: overlay is not defined
overlay();
```

I need to access a method that is inside of requireJS in `jquery.vegas`. How can i do that?

```
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    require(["files/jquery.vegas"], function(jQuery) {
        set_overlay = true;
        ...

        function overlay() {
            $.vegas('overlay', {
                src : 'overlays/10.png'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

---

**jquery.vegas**

```
(function($) {
    function loading() {
        if (set_overlay == true) {
            overlay();
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you can't access the function `overlay` since it is a closure function inside  the annonymous function.

If the above code is in your control then I would suggest you to move the function `overlay` to a shared context between these two methods

ie

```
function overlay() {
    $.vegas('overlay', {
        src : 'overlays/10.png'
    });
}
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    require(["files/jquery.vegas"], function(jQuery) {
        set_overlay = true;
        ...

    });
});

(function($) {
    function loading() {
        if (set_overlay == true) {
            overlay();
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```